# align div right (not to right screen edge)

Tags: css, html, css-float, right-align

I'm just learning and I'm trying to make my 4 div's layout to my desired page size (not to whatever size the user's window is open to). Basic problem, but I can't get my right div to attach to the left div and not necessarily the right side of the user's window.

Here is my code and thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>all.about.me</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='me_stylesheet.css'/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <p>March 02, 2014
            <br><br>Hello.
            <br>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div id="left"> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">    </div>
      <div id="footer">
         </a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p
{
    font:10px verdana,sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

body
{
    background-color: red;
}

div {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

#header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both;
}


#left {
    height: 385px;
    width: 122px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#right {
    height: 385px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I know it's a basic question and I could probably find the answer on Google, but you coders in here always have different and unique ways of doing things that really does inspire creative coding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wrap the elements inside a fixed `width` container element

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Can you be a bit clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `float: left` on both `.left` and `.right`. That will place the right div to the right next to the left div.

http://jsfiddle.net/AB2VE/1/

Comment: This was the simplest answer to achieve my goal. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` and `float:right` on left and right elements. Use `display: inline-block`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AB2VE/)

Also, you can just use `float:left` on `left` element and remove `float:right` on `right` element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AB2VE/2/)

```
#left {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 385px;
   width: 122px;
   background-color: black;
   //float: left;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

```
#right {
   display: inline-block;    
   height: 385px;
   width: 300px;
   background-color: black;
   //float: right;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

Comment: This won't answer, he is using `float`, your answer should use `float`, you can post this as an alternate

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks, I've updated my answer to use only `float:left`.

Answer (score 1):

All yo have to do is to wrap your elements in a `div` and give it the with of your desired page like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DDpRz/7/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <p>March 02, 2014
            <br/>
            <br/>Hello.
            <br/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width:600px;
}
p {
    font:10px verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
body {
    background-color: red;
}
div {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
#left {
    height: 385px;
    width: 122px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#right {
    height: 385px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I like this and will use this also. I'd give you a green check mark also if they allowed me to give two. Thank You.

Comment: @user254005 Glad I could help, you can always upvote this answer if it helped you (by clicking the up arrow on top left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to do:

1. Use a `.wrap`

   ```
   .wrap {width: 900px; margin: auto;}
   ```

   And put all the HTML Content under it. This centers the contents.
2. Remove `float`s. In your code, remove `float: left` and `float: right` for the `#left` and `#right`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DDpRz/6/)

```
#left {
    height: 385px;
    width: 122px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make your 'right div' (div#right) attach to your 'left div' (div#left), simply put div#right inside div#left, making it a child. and position it relative to it's parent container.. which requires div#left to have a position style set to relative.

Your css should be as followed;

### CSS

```
div#left {
height: 385px;
width: 122px;
background-color: black;
display:block;
position:relative;
}

div#right {
height: 385px;
width: 300px;
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
left:100%;
top:0;
display:block;
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>all.about.me</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='me_stylesheet.css'/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <p>March 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2014
            <br /><br />Hello.
            <br />
         </p>
      </div>
      <div id="left">
        <div id="right"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can add float:left to div#left if you want, but I don't see the point in the example context.

When you float objects, you need to have a wrapper div that has a css declaration of 'clear:both'.. it's also a good idea to set the overflow declaration. Certain display issues may arise on older browsers.. and even some modern ones.